# Windows keeps a listening socket for a non-existent process indefinitely

Tags: windows, networking

On Windows, after process 628 (my app) has exited, tcpview shows:

```
Process        PID Pro Local Address Local Port Remote Address  Rem Port State
-------------- --- --- ------------- ---------- --------------- -------- -----------
<non-existent> 628 TCP 0.0.0.0       http       0.0.0.0         0        LISTENING
<non-existent> 628 TCP 0.0.0.0       https      0.0.0.0         0        LISTENING
<non-existent> 628 TCP 0.0.0.0       http       x.x.x.x         xxxxx    ESTABLISHED
```

I was able to kill the ESTABLISHED connection with tcpview, but can't kill the LISTENING ones (as admin) with tcpview or CurrPorts. The LISTENING connections remained indefinitely (>24 hours), preventing the app from binding to port 80 and 443 when restarted ("[10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted").

When I added the SO_REUSEADDR option before binding the listening socket, the app still couldn't bind the ports, this time with "[10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions".

My Questions:

- Does it make any sense for the listening socket to be kept after the owning process is gone? It's not in half-closed state, since no connection has been established.
- Is it expected that a socket of a non-existent process will linger indefinitely?
- Are these known bugs in Windows/Winsocks?

Thanks!

Comment: No, no, and don't know. I would reboot. Is the problem reproducible?

Comment: Does the process launch subprocesses?  If so, are any of them still running?

Comment: How are you cleaning up the socket and what language/api/framework are you using here?  Possibilities include not shutting down the socket properly (or at all), not calling WSAShutdown the same number of times you call WSAStartup (if you're using winsock directly), or a zombie process (previous comment- have an upvote).  Have you tried looking at what's running under your app with process explorer and see if there's something not being shut down somewhere?